# Select Multiple Columns From Sub Query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hope some SqL guru can advice.  I would like to select multiple columns from a sub select if that makes sense.

Here is a WORKING example.

```
SELECT
    customer.id as 'Customer ID'
    customer.name as 'Customer Name' ,
    (
        SELECT
            sum(bookings.commission)
        FROM
            bookings
        WHERE
            bookings.customer_id = c.id
    ) AS 'Customer Commission' ,
FROM
    customers AS c
WHERE
    c.status = 'active'
```

But I would like more data ie.

```
SELECT
    customer.id as 'Customer ID'
    customer.name as 'Customer Name' ,
    (
        SELECT
            sum(bookings.commission),
            sum(bookings.order_total)
        FROM
            bookings
        WHERE
            bookings.customer_id = c.id
    ) AS 'Customer Commission' ,
FROM
    customers AS c
WHERE
    c.status = 'active'
```

Notice Order Total in the second example. I know I can do multiple (SELECT..) but I need allot more than in the example and would be way to slow.

Hope you can advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT c.id as customer_id, c.name as customer_name,
       b.commission, b.order_total
FROM customers c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT b.customer_id, SUM(b.commission) as commission,
             SUM(b.order_total) as order_total
      FROM bookings b
      GROUP BY b.customer_id
     ) b
     ON b.customer_id = c.id
WHERE c.status = 'active'
```

Comment: TY.. Still a slow query but I got a ton of data :-)